# LCD displaying 'b on printout

Tags: python, byte

I've created this code to take a reading from a serial device on ttyUSB0 and then print it on an LCD display I have hooked up to my pi. I have it working to an extent but on my LCD display it is printing the byte symbol "b" followed by my reading. Is their a way to ignore the "b"?

My code:

```
import time
import serial
import I2C_LCD_driver


mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()

print ("Starting Program")
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600,
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
                    )
time.sleep(1)
try:
    ser.write("12345".encode('utf-8'))
    print ("data echo mode enabled")
    while True:
        if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            data = ser.read(size=7)
            print ("Weight", data, "kg")
            mylcd.lcd_display_string("Weight" + str(data), 1)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Exiting Program")

except:
    print ("Error Occurs, Exiting Program")

finally:
    ser.close()
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `str` on a bytes object will return a string that contains quote marks and a b prefix, ex:

```
>>> foo = b"hello"
>>> str(foo)
"b'hello'"
```

Instead, try using `decode`:

```
>>> foo.decode()
'hello'
```

So for your code, that would be `mylcd.lcd_display_string("Weight" + data.decode(), 1)`